# T-SQL - create temporary table with 2 cells from same column in original table plus more columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, subquery

I have table name employeeLog

My columns are:

- EmployeeID (int)
- ParameterID (int)
- Text (nvarchar(50))

`ParameterID` contains index of something that's happened in the organization and `Text` contains the description.

I need to create a temporary table that contain 2 different cases of `ParameterID`. and firstname and lastname from employee table

I tried to do this:

```
insert into @tmpReportTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
(select top 1 Text
 from employeeLog
 where EmployeeID = @employee_id 
 and ParameterID = @event_ID) ,

(select top 1 Text
 from employeeLog
 where EmployeeID = @employee_id and ParameterID = @Location_ID),

(select top 1 firstname
from employees
where EmployeeID = @employee_id),

(select top 1 LastName
from employees
where EmployeeID = @employee_id),
```

and it work.

Is there a better way to do that or a way that I can insert the firstname and last name in one select?

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

I think you just want this:

```
insert into @tmpReportTable (col1, col2)
    select (select top 1 Text
            from employeeLog
            Where EmployeeID = @employee_id And ParameterID = @event_ID
           ) as event,
           (select top 1 Text
            from  employeeLog
            where EmployeeID = @employee_id And ParameterID = @Location_ID
           ) as Location;
```

These are scalar subqueries and they can go directly in the `SELECT`, not need to put them in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer, you were right that I don't need the for().
I Wanted to know if there is a better way to do that then what I wrote,
so I changed a little bit my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an AND

```
insert into @tmpReportTable (col1, col2)
    select 
        T.Event, T.Location
    from  
        ((select top 1 Text
          from employeeLog
          where EmployeeID  = @employee_id 
            and ParameterID = @event_ID)    as 'Event',
         (select top 1 Text
          from employeeLog
          where EmployeeID  = @employee_id 
            and ParameterID = @Location_ID) as'Location'
        ) as T
```

But as Gordon said I don't think you need a from ( ) clause